# UNION or JOIN for this query

Tags: mysql

I have a `$member_id`, there are 5 tables which this member details are stored in those tables in multiple rows.

For getting out this user data from those tables, I can use `JOIN` and `UNION`:

```
//Using JOIN:
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.id=table3.id AND table1.member_id = '$member_id'

//USING UNION
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE member_id = '$member_id')
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE member_id = '$member_id')
ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
```

Which one is preffered? which one has the better performance? what's the true way while you want to get some information from many tables which are **related with foreign keys?**

Comment: Do the three tables share the same structure (same columns)? If not then it just doesn't make sense to UNION them.

Comment: not at all, each table is completely different from the others, but why it doesn't make scene? I want to know the differents

Comment: UNION would list `apple` and `tomatoes` because some of them are red, i.e. you would get a list where some rows would be from table1, some rows from table2, some rows from table3. In a JOIN you would get all columns of 3 tables into each rows that match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need **all columns in same row you should use join**. For **a row by column you should use union**. This is the criteria. They are no secret.

Remember to use left joins if this column don't appear in all tables:

```
SELECT table0.id as a0, table1.id as a1, table2.id as a2, ...
FROM 
   (select '$member_id' as id from dual ) table0
LEFT outer join table1 ON table1.id=table0.id
Left outer JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id 
LEFT outer JOIN table3 ON table2.id=table3.id
```

Also, in union, you can tag each row:

```
//USING UNION
(SELECT 't1' as t, a FROM t1 WHERE member_id = '$member_id')
UNION ALL
(SELECT 't2' as t, a FROM t2 WHERE member_id = '$member_id')
ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: one of those tables is "favorite_songs", each song has entered as a row which could be related to each member by "member_id" column, there may be 100 songs(rows) in that table for each user, so I should use JOIN, right?

Comment: They are not a 'book answer'. It only depends on the future data usage. Perhaps union with tagged table is your solution. But I can't know that because I don't know what do you want to do with this data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same structure and want to remove duplicate rows you can use UNION otherwise it's better to use JOIN statement